# Splitting a string from right at intervals in python

Tags: python, string, list, split

I'm trying to split a string from the right. Following is the code.

```
string = "abcde" 
n = len(string)
slices = [string[i-3:i] for i in range(n,0,-3)]
print (slices)
```

I get the output as `['cde', '']`. I'm trying to get `['cde', 'ab']`

But when I split it from left it gives the proper output, i.e..,

```
string = "abcde" 
slices = [string[i:i+3] for i in range(0,n,3)]
print (slices)

output: ['abc', 'de']
```

Can anyone point out where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are close. You need to floor the first indexing argument at 0:

```
x = "abcde" 
n = len(x)
slices = [x[max(0,i-3):i] for i in range(n,0,-3)]

['cde', 'ab']
```

The reason your code does not work is because with positive indices, falling off the end means going as far as you can.

While negative indices means *starting from the end*, rather than going to the start and no further.